# How to write formula field without else condition

Tags: formula

I want to write a formula field without an else condition because i want to evaluate the formula only if the conditions are met.

ex

```
IF(status = 'True',Formula, "retain the old values and do not evaluate")
```

I seem to fail to do this in salesforce formulas. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the use case here. You can't make the formula to "not evaluate" the condition. In this case, the ELSE should be probably blank quotes `""`.

Comment: "" blank quote means its updating to blank. i dont want to the formula to run when condition changes. instead it should retain the old value of it .

Comment: As I said, you can't do that. As @Phil W suggests below, use a text field with process builder.

Comment: Hi Nipun, Welcome to SFSE! If you can explain how the current formula is calculated, we may be able to suggest an alternative way to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks all. i switched to a price rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula fields don't have a value stored in the database; they are always computed on demand (e.g. when querying that field against one or more objects). Therefore for what you are trying to do, a formula field isn't appropriate.

Perhaps you should switch to using a "real" field with a process builder flow, set to run on update of the object, that updates the field with a required value if a specific condition is met.

Take a look at the [Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_overview.htm&type=5) for more information, or take the [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation/process_builder).